How to run Selenium on AWS Lambda with Python versions greater than 3.7
I'm trying to use Selenium with AWS Lambda for web scraping tasks using Python. However, I'm encountering difficulties when trying to run Selenium on Lambda with Python versions greater than 3.7.
During my research, I found that many tutorials and resources only cover Python 3.7 or earlier versions, and the solutions provided are not compatible with newer Python versions. Can anyone provide guidance on how to properly set up and run Selenium on AWS Lambda using Python versions 3.8 or 3.9?
I've tried various approaches, including using custom layers with pre-installed Selenium and WebDriver like ch, where I zip them and create two file namely python and chrome driver but I keep encountering issues like Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
I have followed this arcticle from medium ->
https://freedium.cfd/https://medium.com/@yashbansal042/running-selenium-on-steroids-the-aws-lambdas-way-3461a22a5406
as well as previous post on overflow where they recommended this video ->
https://youtu.be/jWqbYiHudt8?si=iJrfXEDYxKTFVDaS
But I always fail to execute and make it work?
this is code inside the lambda and the error I recently encountered
Python code ->
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    options = Options()
    options.binary_location = '/opt/headless-chromium'
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--single-process')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
    
    driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
    title = driver.title

    driver.close()
    driver.quit()

    response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": title
    }

    return response 

Error ->
Test Event Name
test

Response
{
  "errorMessage": "Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home\n",
  "errorType": "WebDriverException",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 12, in lambda_handler\n    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py\", line 73, in __init__\n    self.service.start()\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py\", line 81, in start\n    raise WebDriverException(\n"
  ]
}

Function Logs
/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_profile.py:208: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
if setting is None or setting is '':
START RequestId: 43b2b545-929e-4a04-a4f4-cf4808e062ec Version: $LATEST
LAMBDA_WARNING: Unhandled exception. The most likely cause is an issue in the function code. However, in rare cases, a Lambda runtime update can cause unexpected function behavior. For functions using managed runtimes, runtime updates can be triggered by a function change, or can be applied automatically. To determine if the runtime has been updated, check the runtime version in the INIT_START log entry. If this error correlates with a change in the runtime version, you may be able to mitigate this error by temporarily rolling back to the previous runtime version. For more information, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-update.html
[ERROR] WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 12, in lambda_handler
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(END RequestId: 43b2b545-929e-4a04-a4f4-cf4808e062ec
REPORT RequestId: 43b2b545-929e-4a04-a4f4-cf4808e062ec  Duration: 7.77 ms   Billed Duration: 8 ms   Memory Size: 1000 MB    Max Memory Used: 47 MB  Init Duration: 342.71 ms

Request ID
43b2b545-929e-4a04-a4f4-cf4808e062ec

Photos ->

and similarly of Python.zip which contains Selenium

did you manage to get this working? I'm having the same issue, been fighting with this for over a week now. I'm kinda giving up and setting up an ec2 instead

i did solve the issue
